# efficiently querying associated aggregates with active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

Let's say you have this:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
end
```

For some admin interface, I want to render a table with these data points:

Event Name, Total Orders in the last 2 weeks, Total Orders

"last 2 weeks" can just be created_at > 2.weeks.ago

How do I efficiently query the first 20 events and display this data?  That is, I don't want N+1 
queries on this page.

The events are currently coming out of ThinkingSphinx.  I also have Redis at my disposal if it would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could use eager loading in ActiveRecord. It will reduce the queries from N+1 to just 2 queries.

In your EventsController you could add:

```
def index
  @events = Event.includes(:orders)
end
```

More details can be found in the [eager loading docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations).